# Is it okay to place PrintWriters in java List or Collection?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a server using Sockets, and I am trying to find a way to add multiple sockets to the server by using some sort of array/list/collection.

At the moment I am trying a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but with my not-great knowledge about how Lists and PrintWriters work, I don't think that using a List is what I want to do.

This in my main class is what raises my question:

```
protected CopyOnWriteArrayList<ClientConnection> clients;
```

Which forces me to have to close the class as follows:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    for (int n = 0; n < clients.size(); ++n) {

        // Gets the client
        ClientConnection toClose = clients.get(n);

        // Closes it
        toClose.close();

        // Sets the array to be closed.
        clients.set(n, toClose);
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of ClientConnection.java:

```
public class ClientConnection implements java.io.Closeable {
    public Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public InputStreamReader in;

    public ClientConnection (Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void close () throws IOException {
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

What I want to know is if due to cloning with working with lists, is it bad practice to use lists with PrintWriters and other `java.io` classes? If so, what is a good alternative?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code per se, but I do wonder what you mean by "is if due to cloning" -- how is cloning involved here?

Comment: Side note: I would do null checks before calling `close()` on anything, and I don't think that you have to close the socket itself, mainly its streams.

Comment: 1. If `out.close()` fails with an exception remaining two resources won't be closed. So, you may want to put them in multiple try blocks. 2. `clients.set(n, toClose);` is unnecessary, for-each is much better. `for (var toClose : clients) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally fine, you can use lists with PrintWriters and java.io in general

Comment: Thank you, but is my implementation of `close()` ideal, or would it be just fine to write `clients.get(n).close()`?

Comment: Your close implementation is fine.